# Connecting to on-premises SQL Server through Azure Service Bus

Tags: sql-server, azure, azureservicebus

Is this possible through some tcp redirection? If so, how?

Edit: I'd like to connect to on-premises SQL from a worker role to do some custom ATS-SQL synchronization.

Comment: question: curious as to why you need to do this?

Comment: I need to sync-up some data with the on-premise SQL server and do not want for this stuff to run on premise due to hardware constraints.  I'm also weary of Azure Connect because it is not yet released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About 18 months ago, Clemens Vasters posted an article about building a Port Bridge over the Service Bus, which demonstrates how to connect to an on-premises SQL Server database. No use of Azure Connect. The article is [here](http://vasters.com/clemensv/PermaLink,guid,3e35d8bd-b755-453f-8c63-1a57c570eb4c.aspx).

This is just a sample, and not necessarily considered production-ready, but should hopefully get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out the new Service Bus EAI & EDI Labs Release.  It provides connectivity to various on-premise systems including SQL Server.  The connectivity is provided using Service Bus Relay, and may be exactly what you are asking for.  In the process, we can do transformations of the data on the cloud etc.

It is not in production yet, but we would like to get feedback on this.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/12/16/announcing-the-service-bus-eai-amp-edi-labs-release.aspx

Thanks,
Sameer [MSFT]
sameerch @ microsft.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Sync Framework to synchronise your data?

[Sync Framework: SQL Server to SQL Azure Synchronization](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1591.aspx)

Comment: I have.  Unfortunately, I am not syncing with SQL to SQL.. but am syncing with SQL to ATS

Comment: Perhaps make that more explicit in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Much as I love the idea of routing raw TCP traffic through the service bus the performance is going to be pants (sorry Clemens...)

Have you taken a look at WIndows Azure COnnect
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/virtual-network/

This will basically give you a VPN like connection back to your on-premise SQL Server. If you can make it work (i.e. can install the agent locally) then this is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is data sync, have you looked at SQL Azure data sync?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-data-sync-overview.aspx

Comment: SQL Azure data sync only syncs SQL-based to SQL-based afaik.  I need to sync ATS to SQL